# I need to run two different sessions in one thread group

Tags: java, jmeter

I'm testing a scenario where one user adds a new user to the database, and that new user attempts to log in. I need to be able to run the whole process paralell, but the login attempt needs to happen after the addition of the user.

The problem is for some reason the Cookie Manager wasn't able to provide a proper sessionID from the setUp Thread and I had to use a Header Manager to insert the cookie. This means when the new user logs in it  will "break" the original user's login session, and in a paralel run it will cause it to not be able to add the new user, as the system think it's the new user logged in, who doesn't have authorization do do the things the previous user was supposed to.

I'm thinking of two ways to solve this.

1. put the new user's login in a different thread group that will get a new session ID, however:

   - How do I ensure it will be tied to the run of the original thread? In Short: I need to ansure that one thread creates another thread, and for it to work in parallel.
2. find some way to clear the sessionID from the header manager, call it before the new user logs in, this way it will request a new sessionID.

```
import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control.Header;
import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control.HeaderManager;

HeaderManager headerManager = sampler.getHeaderManager();

if (headerManager != null) {
    headerManager.add(new Header("HeaderName", ""));
}
```

I tried this, but instead of clearing the value of the HeaderName header it instead inserted a new Header, called HeaderName with an empty value.

```
import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control.Header;
import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control.HeaderManager;

HeaderManager headerManager = sampler.getHeaderManager();

if (headerManager != null) {
    headerManager.add(new Header("HeaderName", ""));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. HTTP Cookie Manager doesn't share cookies between thread groups.
2. HTTP Cookie Manager keeps separate cookies for separate users, they are not shared between threads. See [Thread-local storage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread-local_storage) article to get understanding on how to use separate memory for separate processes.

   If Cookie Manager doesn't capture a cookie from the response it might be the case it's not valid. You can try using less restricting implementation like `netscape` and/or set `CookieManager.check.cookies` property to `false`
3. If you want to copy a cookie to another Thread Group or use it elsewhere you can turn on storing of cookies into JMeter Variables by setting [`CookieManager.save.cookies`](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#miscellaneous) property to `true` and then [convert JMeter Variable holding the cookie value into a JMeter Property](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-variables)
4. According to the [standard](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2616) duplicate headers are allowed so if you want to change the value of a header you need to remove an existing one first with the following line:

   ```
   headerManager.removeHeaderNamed("HeaderName");
   ```